How to use a local GeoJSON file (world_110m.json) with Plotly in PySide6 to prevent external fetching?
I’m trying to display a choropleth map using Plotly and PySide6. I want to ensure that all resources, including world_110m.json, are loaded locally and not fetched from the CDN. I already have a custom GeoJSON file (map1.geojson) and the required world_110m.json file stored locally.
Here’s the code I’m using:
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from pathlib import Path
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import json

sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Load the GeoJSON file
geojson_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'map1.geojson'
with open(geojson_path, 'r') as f:
    geojson_data = json.load(f)

# Create the choropleth map
fig = go.Figure(go.Choropleth(
    geojson=geojson_data,
    locations=[feature['properties']['region'] for feature in geojson_data['features']],
    z=[1 for _ in geojson_data['features']],  
    hoverinfo='location+z',
    colorbar_title="Values"
))

# Set layout to configure the map appearance
fig.update_layout(
    geo=dict(
        visible=True,
        showland=True,
        landcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
        projection_type="mercator",
        showframe=False,
    ),
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    width=800,
    height=600
)

# Get the directory of the current script to load the local JS
CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
local_js_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "plotly-latest.min.js").toString()

# HTML content with local plotly JS
raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
raw_html += f'<script src="{local_js_url}"></script></head>'
raw_html += '<body>'
raw_html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
raw_html += '</body></html>'

# Create the QWebEngineView and load the HTML
view = QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml(raw_html, QUrl.fromLocalFile(CURRENT_DIRECTORY))  # baseUrl to resolve resources
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())

Problem:
When I run this code, Plotly tries to fetch the world_110m.json file from an external CDN (https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json) and throws the following error:
js: Uncaught (in promise) Error: unexpected error while fetching topojson file at https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json

I want to:

Prevent Plotly from fetching the world_110m.json file from the CDN.
Load the world_110m.json file from my local directory instead.

How can I modify the code to ensure Plotly uses the local world_110m.json file for the map background instead of fetching it from the internet? Is there a way to explicitly provide the file path or bypass this default behavior?
Additional Information:
I’ve come across a solution that involves setting up a Flask app to serve the world_110m.json file locally. However, this requires setting up a web server, which adds complexity (especially for someone unfamiliar with Flask or server configuration).
Is there a more direct method to accomplish this without setting up a web server? For example, can Plotly access the world_110m.json file directly from the filesystem or through a simpler mechanism?
